# Display data according to date in listView

Tags: php, android, date, listview

This is my **Activtiy A**, where all the data is retrieved from `MySQL` into `listView`. (select data based on given name and month)

[image]

```
<?php
  define('HOST','127.0.0.1:3307');
  define('USER','root');
  define('PASS','');
  define('DB','androiddb');

  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('unable to connect');

  $name = $_GET['name'];

  $month = $_GET['month'];

 $sql = "select * from information WHERE name= '". $name."' and MONTH(date) = '".$month."'";

  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $result=array();


  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result,array('id'=>$row[0],'name'=>$row[1],'weather'=>$row[2],'date'=>$row[3],'status'=>$row[4],
      'time_in'=>$row[5], 'time_out'=>$row[6]));
  }

 echo (json_encode(array("result"=>$result)));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

How to display the data according to date ? I want `2016-01-30` on the top and `2016-01-02` display in the lowest ? Thanks

Comment: Just add an order by clause in the SQL `select * from information WHERE name= '". $name."' and MONTH(date) = '".$month."' ORDER BY date"`

Comment: @TahTatsumoto THANKS !! but now the highest is `2016-01-02`. How to display date by descender ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment was to sort it by ascending order. If you want descending, just change it to

```
"select * from information WHERE name= '". $name."' and MONTH(date) = '".$month."' ORDER BY date DESC"
```